# Pre functions for TableGateway in zend framework 2 (zf2)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db, tablegateway

I am using table gateway in zf2. This is simple model table with following working functions. I can insert or update records but I need to know how can we define functions like beforeInsert or beforeUpdate like we do in doctrine(beforePersist).

```
namespace Application\Model\AnyModel;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class AnyModelTable {

protected $tableGateway;

public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway) {
    $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
}

public function fetchAll() {
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
    return $resultSet;
}

public function getRecord($id) {
    $id = (int) $id;
    $rowSet = $this->tableGateway->select(array('id' => $id));
    $row = $rowSet->current();
    if (!$row) {
        throw new \Exception("Could not found record with $id");
    }
    return $row;
}

public function saveRecord(AnyModel $record) {
    $data = array(
        'name' => $record->name,
        'description' => $record->description,
        'status' => $record->status,
        'created_by' => $record->created_by,
        'created_on' => $record->created_on,
    );
    $id = (int) $record->id;
    if ($id == 0) {
        $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
    } else {
        if ($this->getUser($id)) {
            $this->tableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
        } else {
            throw new \Exception("Could not update user with id $id");
        }
    }
}

public function deleteRecord($id) {
    $this->tableGateway->delete(array('id' => $id));
}

public function getArrayCopy() {
    return get_object_vars($this);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and flexible solution would be to use an event manager instance into your table mapper and trigger the events in the correct place.

I'll expand on the [Event Manager's quick start example](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html#quick-start); ideally allot of this bloat could be abstracted out in an abstract class.

```
<?php
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManager;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerAwareInterface;

class Foo implements EventManagerAwareInterface
{
    const EVENT_INSERT_PRE   = 'insert.pre';
    const EVENT_INSERT_POST  = 'insert.post';
    const EVENT_INSERT_ERROR = 'insert.error';

    protected $events;

    public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        $events->setIdentifiers(array(
            __CLASS__,
            get_called_class(),
        ));
        $this->events = $events;

        $this->init($events);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEventManager()
    {
        if (null === $this->events) {
            $this->setEventManager(new EventManager());
        }
        return $this->events;
    }

    protected function init(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        $events->attach(
            static::EVENT_INSERT_PRE, // event that we listen to
            array($this, 'onPreInsert') // The method that is triggered
            100 // The priority 
        );
    }

    public function save(AnyModel $record) 
    {
        try {
            $em = $this->getEventManager();

            $data = array('foo' => 'bar');

            $em->trigger(static::EVENT_INSERT_PRE, compact('record', 'data'));
            //...
            $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
            //...
            $em->trigger(static::EVENT_INSERT_POST, compact('record'));

            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $em->trigger(static::EVENT_INSERT_ERROR, compact('e'));

            return false;
        }
    }

    public function onPreInsert(EventInterface $event)
    {
        $data = $events->getParam('data', false);

        if ($data !== $someValidDataTypeOrValue) {
            return;
        }
        /** do stuff **/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instantiate a TableGateway

```
use use Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature;    

/** @var \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway $memberTable */
$memberTable = TableFactory::get('member',new Feature\EventFeature());

/** @var \Zend\EventManager\ListenerAggregateInterface $eventService->getListener('Member') */
$eventService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Event');

$memberTable->getFeatureSet()
            ->getFeatureByClassName('Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\EventFeature')
            ->getEventManager()
            ->attachAggregate($eventService->getListener('Member'));
```

this is the MemberListener

```
namespace Fselab\EventModel\Listeners;

use Zend\EventManager\ListenerAggregateInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\EventFeature;

class Member implements ListenerAggregateInterface
{
    private $handle;

    protected $listeners = array();

    function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
            $this->listeners[] = $events->attach(EventFeature::EVENT_PRE_INSERT, function(EventInterface $e){
                $insert = $e->getParam('insert');

                return;
            }, 100);
    }

    public function detach(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        foreach ($this->listeners as $index => $listener) {
            if ($events->detach($listener)) {
                unset($this->listeners[$index]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```